# NERDTree on Vim

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I'm running into a problem that I've never really ran into before with my setup. I've set up my NERDTree config in the `.vimrc` so that every time that I open a directory NERDTree will also open but it should also stay open when I open a file (NERDTree to the left and buffers to the right) however, it doesn't do that. Right now it does open NERDTree but once I click `enter` on the file I want to open, NERDTree closes and I'm left only with the file I opened (no NERDTree on the left). The code is as follows:

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
```

this is the config I've been using on my `.vimrc` for NERDTree for quite some time, usually I just copy+paste my `.vimrc` into any new install of vim and it works after setting everything up. And in this case, everything else works, and even NERDTree, but it just closes after I open the file.

Comment: What does `:echo NERDTreeQuitOnOpen` show when you are in the context that is causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

I have these in my config. This works well.

```python
"Open NERDtree automatically on vim startup
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree

"close NERDtree if that is the last window left
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
" don't quit NERDTree after opening a buffer
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 0
" start NERDTree when vim starts
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```